# Better way to write this function: list to matrix (= list of lists)

Tags: list, haskell, matrix

Is there a better way to write this function (i.e. in one line via folds)?

```
--              list -> rowWidth -> list of lists
listToMatrix :: [a] -> Int -> [[a]]
listToMatrix [] _ = []
listToMatrix xs b = [(take b xs)] ++ (listToMatrix (drop b xs) b)
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually this is a nice case for unfolding. `Data.List` method `unfoldr`, unlike folding a list, creates a list to a from a seed value by applying a function to it up until this function returns `Nothing`. Until we reach the terminating condition that will return `Nothing` the function returns `Just (a,b)` where `a` is the current generated item of the list and `b` is the next value of the seed. In this particular case our seed value is the given list.

```
import Data.List
chunk :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunk n = unfoldr (\xs -> if null xs then Nothing else Just (splitAt n xs))

*Main> chunk 3 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
*Main> chunk 3 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10]]
```

Comment: You can also use `null xs` instead of `xs == []`, so you can drop the `Eq` constraint.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a better way to write this function. But I don't think that making it one line is going to improve anything.

#### Use the prepending operator `(:)` instead of list concatenation `(++)` for single-element prepending

The expression `[(take b xs)] ++ (listToMatrix (drop b xs) b)` is inefficient. I don't mean inefficient in terms of performances, because the compiler probably optimizes that, but, here, you are constructing a list, and then calling a function on it (`(++)`) which is going to deconstruct it by pattern matching. You could instead build your list directly using the `(:)` data constructor, which allows you to prepend a single element to your list. The expression becomes `take b xs : listToMatrix (drop b xs) b`

#### Use [`splitAt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:splitAt) to avoid running through the list twice

```
import Data.List (splitAt)

listToMatrix :: [a] -> Int -> [[a]]
listToMatrix xs b = row : listToMatrix remaining b
    where (row, remaining) = splitAt b xs
```

#### Ensure the correctness of your data by using `Maybe`

```
listToMatrix :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe [[a]]
listToMatrix xs b
    | length xs `mod` b /= 0 = Nothing
    | null xs   = Just []
    | otherwise = Just $ row : listToMatrix remaining b
    where (row, remaining) = splitAt b xs
```

You can even avoid checking every time if you have the right number of elements by defining a helper function:

```
listToMatrix :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe [[a]]
listToMatrix xs b
    | length xs `mod` b /= 0 = Nothing
    | otherwise = Just (go xs)
    where go [] = []
          go xs = row : go remaining
              where (row, remaining) = splitAt b xs
```

#### Ensure the correctness of your data by using safe types

A matrix has te same number of elements in each row, whereas nested lists don't allow to ensure that kind of conditions. To be certain that every row has the same number of elements, you can either use a library such as [`matrix`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/matrix-0.3.5.0/docs/Data-Matrix.html) or [`hmatrix`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix-0.18.0.0/docs/Numeric-LinearAlgebra-HMatrix.html)

Comment: You rightly suggest using `splitAt` to avoid an unnecessary extra traversal but then use `length`, which causes an unnecessary extra traversal. An alternative would be to check that `length row == b` in the case when `remaining` is empty, i.e., that the last row has the expected row length.

Comment: Rein Henrichs: Yeah but wouldn't that mean that the function would do every recursion until the last row to find that the number of elements doesn't match ? My solution allows these case to be detected right away, at the first iteration.

Comment: Checking the length doesn't allow the failure to be detected "right away": it allows the failure to be detected once you traverse the entire list. You have to traverse the list either way. Recursion is cheap while traversing the whole list an extra time is expensive.

Comment: Also, as a general rule, I don't like making the successful path slower in order to make the failure path faster.

Comment: How is recursion cheap ? We use `splitAt` which traverses the first `b` elements of the list. If we give a list of length `n` to `listToMatrix`, where `b` does not divide `n`, we would have to traverse `div n b * b` elements. Or is it a lazyness trick ?

Comment: You have to scrutinize the spine of the list at least once either way. Doing as I suggested scrutinizes the spine exactly once. Your method scrutinizes the spine once for the failure case but *twice* for the success case. This is strictly worse.

Comment: Do you think that `length` doesn't scrutinize the spine of the list?

Comment: Do you mind editing my post, because I'm not 100% sure I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

No, although I wish `chunksOf` was in the standard library. You can get that from here if you want: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.2/docs/Data-List-Split.html

Note a better definition would be:

```
listToMatrix xs b = (take b xs) : (listToMatrix (drop b xs) b)
```

although this might compile to the same core. You could also use `splitAt`, though again this is likely to perform the same.

```
listToMatrix xs b = let (xs,xss) = splitAt b xs in xs : listToMatrix xss
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, the idea is to take all the chunks of the main list, it is a different approach but basicly do the same:

```
Prelude> let list2Matrix n xs = map (\(x ,y)-> (take n) $ (drop (n*x)) y) $ zip [0..] $ replicate (div (length xs)  n) xs
Prelude> list2Matrix 10 [1..100]
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],[21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30],[31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40],[41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50],[51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60],[61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70],[71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80],[81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90],[91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100]]
```